# character string literal and string literal in standard?

Tags: c, string, constants, string-literals

I am confused by these four terms:

- character string literal
- character constants
- string literal.
- multibyte character sequence

And reading this quote in [C Standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf):

> **A character string literal need not be a string** (see 7.1.1), because
>   a null character may be embedded in it by a `\0` escape sequence.

What is meant by the first part ?

Comment: string literal == character string literal

Comment: @DYZ Not quite. The standard is talking about character, UTF-8 and wide string literals. Nevertheless, I think the question is rather about literal vs string.

Comment: A string, by definition, is terminated by a null character. A character string literal may contain null characters inside it. Therefore, a character string literal may not be a string.

Comment: Note that the address of a literal may be taken like `&"X"`.  Not so for a constant like `&'Y'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A *string-literal* is

- either a *character string literal*, e.g. `"abc"`;
- or *UTF-8 string literal*, e.g. `u8"abc"`;
- or *wide string literal*, e.g. `L"abc"`.

From the standard (emphasis mine):

> A *character string literal* is a sequence of zero or more multibyte characters enclosed in
>   double-quotes, as in `"xyz"`. A *UTF−8 string literal* is the same, except prefixed by u8.
>   A *wide string literal is the same*, except prefixed by the letter `L`, `u`, or `U`.
> ....
>   In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
>   character sequence that results from a string literal or literals. <sup>78)</sup>
>
> <sub>78) A string literal need not be a string (see 7.1.1), because a null character may be embedded in it by a
>   \0 escape sequence.</sub>

---

> A *string* is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including ***the first null
>   character***.

So a string literal may have `\0` also in the middle or even at the beginning, for instance `"a\0b"` or `"\0ab"`. I think this is what the footnote is saying.

A *character constant* is a *c-char-sequence* (usually a single character) in single quotes, with a possible prefix `L`/`u`/`U`.

> An integer character constant is a sequence of one or more multibyte characters enclosed
>   in single-quotes, as in `'x'`. A wide character constant is the same, except prefixed by the
>   letter `L`, `u`, or `U`.

So the terminology is not very symmetric, IMO. E.g. wide character constant is *a particular case* of character constant. However both character string literal and wide string literal *belong to* string literals.

Comment: Looks like you missed an underscore. Hope I fixed it right.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks! I think we were editing in parallel ).

Comment: So the character string literal containg null characters inside  is also terminated by null character right ?

Comment: @Sabrina No, that's not right. Consider `char a[] = "x\0y";` `strlen(a)` will be 1, but `sizeof(a)` will be *4*, and `a[2]` will be `'y'`.

Comment: @zwol Which question do you answer with "_No, that's not right_"? Could it be a deleted comment or do I overlook something?

Comment: @Sabrina Possibly I have misunderstood. You said "the character string literal containg null characters inside is also terminated by null character right ?" I thought you were proposing that the string literal would be _cut off_ by the first of the interior nulls, which is not true. Did you instead mean that an interior null does not prevent the compiler from adding another null at the end? That _is_ true.

Comment: @Sabrina ... so which thing did you mean?